# Codeigniter application: how can I display pagination as JSON?

Tags: json, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3

I am working on a **blog application** with **Codeigniter 3.1.8**.

Currently, its admin area is well separated from the frontend.

In the frontend, I have managed to replace "classic" Codeigniter views with JSONS. (the JSONS are displayed and "handled" with AngularJS).

Here is the code in the **controller** for **all the posts**:

```
private function _initPagination($path, $totalRows, $query_string_segment = 'page') {
        //load and configure pagination 
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url($path);
        $config['query_string_segment'] = $query_string_segment; 
        $config['enable_query_strings'] =TRUE;
        $config['reuse_query_string'] =TRUE;
        $config['total_rows'] = $totalRows;
        $config['per_page'] = 12;
        if (!isset($_GET[$config['query_string_segment']]) || $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] < 1) {
            $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] = 1;
        }
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $limit = $config['per_page'];
        $offset = ($this->input->get($config['query_string_segment']) - 1) * $limit;

        return ['limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset];
    }

    public function index() {

    //call initialization method
        $config = $this->_initPagination("/", $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows());

        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
        $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();  

        //use limit and offset returned by _initPaginator method
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($config['limit'], $config['offset']);

        // All posts
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }
```

What I have not been able to do (despite tormenting my brain), is display the **pagination** of the posts as JSON too.

In the **Posts** model:

```
public function get_posts($limit, $offset) {
    $this->db->select('posts.*,categories.name as post_category');
    $this->db->order_by('posts.id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->join('categories', 'posts.cat_id = categories.id', 'inner');
    $query = $this->db->get('posts', $limit, $offset);
    return $query->result();
}
```

My pagination view:

```
<div class="pagination-container text-center">
    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** I have pushed the entire **[application](https://github.com/Ajax30/ciapi)** to Github. You can have an in-depth look if you want. To create all the MySQL tables, run the Install controller. :)

What shall I do?

Comment: if you use bootstrap i suggest https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ for bootstrap v3 and https://morgul.github.io/ui-bootstrap4/ for bootstrap v4 - both of them include a pagination directive.

Comment: @sintakonte my posts are already paginated, from the back-end (PHP). Since the pagination is not visible in the front-end, I csn only see the first 12 posts. Thai is the problem.

Comment: im not talking about pagination client side - i'm talking about using that directive for server side pagination. Its probably a good idea to post the entire circle here (CI list view, AngularJS Controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

create new class in application/libraries/MY_Pagination.php

```
<?php

class MY_Pagination extends CI_Pagination
{
    public function get_as_array()
    {
        return [
            'total_rows' => $this->total_rows,
            'per_page' => $this->per_page,
            'cur_page' => $this->cur_page,
        ];
    }
}
```

in your controller use:

```
public function index() {

    //call initialization method
    $config = $this->_initPagination("/", $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows());

    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();

    //this is the line I added
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->get_as_array();

    $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();  

    //use limit and offset returned by _initPaginator method
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($config['limit'], $config['offset']);

    // All posts
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

For Angular can use something like https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/overview

Comment: My pagination looks completely different. I don't know of the existence of "CI_Pagination" in Codeigniter. Also, the pagination I already have works fine. My problem is *not being able to display it as JSON*.

Comment: You already use CI_Pagination ($this->load->library('pagination');) but create_links() methods from CI_Pagination return a html block. That is why I propose to extend the CI_Pagination functionality to return array instead of HTML. Here you can find the implementation of pagination that already you use https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Pagination.php

Comment: I need a way to make the pagination part of the JSON that *already* displays the posts, pages, etc 9see the **[application](https://github.com/Ajax30/ciapi)** on my Github account). I need this done with as little change to what I already have as possible. I appreciate the code you have provided, but I don't understand how and where it fits in my application. I am looking for a *bug-fix*. Best regards. :)

Comment: I understand what you want. It is not a bug it is a refactoring because you moved the view from Codeigniter to Angular (From MWC in Codeigniter you now have MC in Codeigniter and W in Angular). If you add the code I have sent you, your JSON will lock something like this: {"pagination":{"total_rows": 100, "per_page": 12, "cur_page": 1}, "pages": {....}, "categories": {....}, "posts": {....}}. I tried to make a pull request but I don't have enought rights :(.

Comment: I don't know where to add it. Nor whst code to replace/delete. Please put it in context. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer. After you create MY_Pagination.php you only need to add a new line in your index method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200129/discussion-between-razvan-zamfir-and-doru-d).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

request the `create_links()` string via ajax and append it to your page wherever you need. (*btw you can style it however you want and return it already styled*)

```
echo json_encode(['pagination' => $this->pagination->create_links()]);
```

or you can return all bits of information you need and process it yourself, all you need is `current_page` which you have already requested or get it via `$this->uri->segment(3)` and you need total number of pages which is `total_rows/per_page`.

```
echo json_encode(['total_pages' => $config['total_rows']/$config['per_page'], 'current_page' => $this->uri->segment(3)]);
```

Comment: Using `echo json_encode(['pagination' => $this->pagination->create_links()]);` does not return the pagination items in JSON format. Besides, my `pagination.php` is used in the backed of the application too, so I need it unchanged.

Comment: As for `echo json_encode(['total_pages' => $config['total_rows']/$config['per_page'], 'current_page' => $this->uri->segment(3)]);` I don't see where it would fit in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will give you idea on how pagination is generated by Codeigniter.

**Please Note: This is reference from CI 4 Documentation Version 4.0.0 rc1**
**Link:** https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/pagination.html?highlight=pagination

```
<?php $pager->setSurroundCount(2) ?>

<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination">
    <?php if ($pager->hasPrevious()) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?= $pager->getFirst() ?>" aria-label="First">
                <span aria-hidden="true">First</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?= $pager->getPrevious() ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php foreach ($pager->links() as $link) : ?>
        <li <?= $link['active'] ? 'class="active"' : '' ?>>
            <a href="<?= $link['uri'] ?>">
                <?= $link['title'] ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>

    <?php if ($pager->hasNext()) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?= $pager->getNext() ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?= $pager->getLast() ?>" aria-label="Last">
                <span aria-hidden="true">Last</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Try sending all required variable used above in example for pagination from your controller as json data to your view and create it same as in example above.

Wish you all the best.

Comment: My posts are already paginated, from the back-end (PHP). Since the pagination is not visible in the front-end, I can only see the first 12 posts. This is the *problem*. I made this application from an **[older](http://code-love.tk/demoblog/)** one that had the shortcoming: the front-end was not well separated from the back-end, so It was not very customisable visually (design wise). So I( turned the admin into an API and used AngularJS (due to its strong template engine) as the front-end. Note: I use CI 3, not 4.

Comment: Hi Razavan Zamfir.. I am sorry my solutions din't work for you.
  
Do your Posts_model have function get_posts() similar to way mention below
  
`code`
    `function get_posts($params = array())`  `{`  `$this->db->order_by('post_id', 'desc');`  `if(isset($params) && !empty($params))`  `{`  `$this->db->limit($params['limit'], $params['offset']);`  `}`  `return $this->db->get('post')->result_array();`  `}`  
  
**Note: I have used array parameter,** make sure limit and offset is correctly configured by your  controller _initPagination function

Comment: I have added the code in the Posts model that addressees the list of posts.

Comment: Ok.. So I think the problem is with offset as you are making json request each time you request index page it will show you only first 12 record as it does not know its current position of pagination. Pagination variable is passed via url. Which can be stored in controller by `$offset = ($this->input->get('per_page')) ? $this->input->get('per_page') : 0;`

Comment: try sending $offset as parameter to _initPagination  and set 

        $limit = RECORDS_PER_PAGE;   $config['base_url'] = site_url('controller_name/index?');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200029/discussion-between-mohsin-mujawar-and-razvan-zamfir).

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if it works

```
private function _initPagination($path, $totalRows, $page_offset) {
        //load and configure pagination 
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config = $this->config->item('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = $path;
        $config['total_rows'] = $totalRows;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $limit = RECORDS_PER_PAGE;
        $offset = $page_offset;

        return ['limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset];
    }

    public function index() {

    $page_offset = ($this->input->get('per_page')) ? $this->input->get('per_page') : 0;

    //call initialization method
        $config = $this->_initPagination(site_url('controller_name/index?'), $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows(), $page_offset);

        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
        $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();  

        //use limit and offset returned by _initPaginator method
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($config['limit'], $config['offset']);

        // All posts
  }
```

Or make it more simple

```
public function index() {

    $params['limit'] = RECORDS_PER_PAGE; 
    $params['offset'] = ($this->input->get('per_page')) ? $this->input->get('per_page') : 0;

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config = $this->config->item('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('controller/index?');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows();
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();  

    //use limit and offset
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($param['limit'],$param['offset']);

  }
```

Comment: The code throws an `Use of undefined constant RECORDS_PER_PAGE - assumed 'RECORDS_PER_PAGE'` error.

Comment: Try numeric value

Comment: Not any different from what I already have, in terms of outcome.

Comment: I have pushed the entire **[application](https://github.com/Ajax30/ciapi)** to Github.  You can have an in-depth look if you want. To create all the MySQL tables, run the *Install* controller. :)